# Cómo crear un menú desplegable en cascada actualizado dinámicamente en Vue Js

Tags: vue.js

Estoy tratando de crear un componente en VueJS, que cuando se proporciona un accesorio de objeto, crea dinamicamente menús desplegables de selección en cada etapa de la jerarquía del objeto.

Es importante destacar que el número de menús desplegables está determinado por las opciones seleccionadas por el usuario, es decir, no se conoce de antemano.

En su mayor parte, he logrado esto con lo siguiente:

```
Vue.component('category-filter', {
  props: {
    taxonomy: Object
  },
  template: `<div><select v-model='selected'><option v-for='(option, index) in options' :key='index'>{{ option }}</option></select><div v-if='selected'><category-filter v-if='Object.keys(taxonomy[selected]).length' :taxonomy='taxonomy[selected]'></category-filter></div>`,
  data: () => ({
    selected: null
  }),
  computed: {
    options() {
      return Object.keys(this.taxonomy)     
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    options: {
      A: {
        A1: {
          A1I: '',
          A1II: ''
        },
        A2: {
          A2I: '',
          A2II: '',
          A2III: ''
        },
        A3: {
          A3I: '',
          A3II: '',
          A3III: '',
          A3IV: ''
        }
      },
      B: {
        B1: {
          B1I: '',
          B1II: ''
        },
        B2: {
          B2I: '',
          B2II: ''
        }
      },
      C: {
        C1: {
          C1I: '',
          C1II: '',
          C1III: '',
          C1IV: ''
        },
        C2: {
          C2I: '',
          C2II: ''
        },
        C3: {
          C3I: '',
          C3II: {
            C3IIA: '',
            C3IIB: '',
            C3IIC: ''
          }
        },
        C4: {
          C4I: '',
          C4II: '',
          C4III: ''
        }
      }
    },
    selected: ''
  })
})
```

Sin embargo, solo funciona si está seleccionando la siguiente opción en la secuencia de menús desplegables.

Entonces, si selecciona A> A1> A1I, por ejemplo, funciona según lo previsto. Pero si luego cambia la opción en el primer menú desplegable a B, las opciones en los menús desplegables posteriores no cambian para reflejar las nuevas opciones que deberían estar disponibles.

Intenté hacer que el valor del accesorio pasado al componente dentro del componente sea un valor calculado, y traté de desacoplar el modelo v en v-bind: `value` y `v-on`: `input` para insertar la actualización en ese momento, y he intentado usar un observador para actualizar el valor de apoyo, pero ninguno de estos ha sido exitoso.

Sospecho que la respuesta puede estar en los ganchos del ciclo de vida del componente, pero si es así, no estoy seguro de dónde o cómo.

Cualquier consejo sera muy apreciado.

Aqui esta [disponible](https://codepen.io/northcode/pen/wvvdqOZ) un codepen de mi componente tal como está actualmente .